# How do you divide a list (indefinite length) randomly into 3 subgroups?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

Lets say that my program asks a user to input a number indefinitely and I appended it in a list.

```
#Given Example:
List = [105, 167, 262, 173, 123, 718, 219, 272, 132]
```

what I wanted to do is to randomly pick any of the numbers so my sample output would be:

```
first = [105, 262, 173]
second = [167, 123, 132]
third = [718, 219,272]
```

Having said, since the user input would be indefinite there will be chances that it would be an odd number.

I am currently using random.sample to choose a number from that list and append it in a list, after that I'll append the sub-groups of list to create a list within a list.

Would be a great help if anyone answers, thanks!

Comment: Why not use `random.shuffle` on the list, then take your pick of something to group the data in chunks from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could shuffle your list with [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [105, 167, 262, 173, 123, 718, 219, 272, 132]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[167, 123, 173, 718, 262, 272, 105, 219, 132]
```

And extract 3 sub-lists with [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6419007). The first list will have indices 0, 3 and 6 from the shuffled `l`, the second list will have indices 1, 4 and 7 and the third will have indices 2, 6 and 8:

```
>>> l[::3]
[167, 718, 105]
>>> l[1::3]
[123, 262, 219]
>>> l[2::3]
[173, 272, 132]
```

As a bonus, it will work with lists of any length:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> [l[x::3] for x in range(3)]
[[2, 4], [1, 5], [3]]
```

You can be sure that every element will appear exactly once in the nested lists.

You could also define more sublists:

```
>>> l = list(range(20))
>>> n = 5
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> [l[x::n] for x in range(n)]
[[5, 18, 9, 4], [11, 12, 1, 15], [13, 3, 6, 8], [17, 0, 14, 2], [10, 16, 7, 19]]
```

Comment: Never thought of that, thank yoy so much!  I was making my life hard by trying to manually append each random generated number.

Answer (score 0):

If List is going to remain short such that you can read it into the memory, then you can use `[random.shuffle][1]`

```
import random
List = [105, 167, 262, 173, 123, 718, 219, 272, 132]

random.shuffle(List)
first = L[0:3]
```

Now use List Comprehension to subtract the original `List` with `first`

```
newList = [item for item in List if item not in first]
```

Now use `newList` for `second` and `third` and you'd be good to go! :)